# oracle apex 20 - cascading list of values does not work e.g. checkbox groups

Tags: oracle-apex

- I added 2 checkbox groups (:P1_G1, :P1_G2) to a Static Content region
- I specified the List of Values ​​SQL queries
  select r, d from code where parent is null
  select r, d from code where instr (',' || parent || ',', ',' ||:P1_G1 || ',')> 0
- I set the Cascading List of Values ​​Parent Items (s)
  :P1_G2 -> :P1_G1

If changed :P1_G1, :P1_G2 does not change.
The List of Values ​​in :P1_G2 does not see the value of :P1_G1, because it has not been updated on the server side.

I could only solve the problem by adding a new item (:P1_G1_ACT), which I added a value to with a dynamic action, and running a "dummy" pl / sql code (x:=1;) and then :P1_G2 List of Values in select in query replace :P1_G1 to :P1_G1_ACT.

Does anyone have a better solution, an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Cascading List of Values you need to specify the items that are used in the SQL in the "Items for submit" field.

This means that if there is a change in the parent item, all the values of the necessary items are sent to the server side

[image]